How to setup a connection to Sharepoint with enterprise app and client secret
I'm trying to connect to sharepoint from a service.
I already registered the app in Entra and succesfully made a connection to sharepoint when using a certificate. But the customer has provides us a clientsecret instead of a certificate. (still made in Entra, so this is not ACS if I understand correctly)
But I can't seem to find a method to provide a client secret for authentication in PnpCore. In Pnp.Framework there is a PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager method that accepts a clientsecret, but then you must pass a user assertion token.
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    var configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

    services.AddPnPCoreAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            var authOptions = new PnPCoreAuthenticationCredentialConfigurationOptions
            {
                ClientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("SharepointConnection:clientId"),
                TenantId = configuration.GetValue<string>("SharepointConnection:tenantId"),
                X509Certificate = new PnPCoreAuthenticationX509CertificateOptions
                {
                    StoreName = StoreName.My,
                    StoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                    Thumbprint = configuration.GetValue<string>("SharepointConnection:thumbPrint")
                }
            };

            options.Credentials.Configurations.Add("SharepointAuth", authOptions);
            options.Credentials.DefaultConfiguration = "SharepointAuth";

            options.Sites.Add("SiteToWorkWith",
                new PnPCoreAuthenticationSiteOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationProviderName = "SharepointAuth"
                });
        });

})



Client Secrets are not supported for app-only authentication. You MUST use a certificate. Note that this can be ANY certificate, i.e. including self-signed ones you (or your customer) created yourself, it does not need to be issued by authority.
The method that works with client secret is for delegated authentication.

What do you mean exactly with client-secrets are "not-supported".
Not supported by the Pnp framework ?
Because the customers has other partners that do connect with a client-secret, so this is probably then with another framework /older version ?
PS I prefer to connect with a certificate. So I will work to that, but was wondering how it is done with client-secret

I actually found a resource that indeed mentions that client-secret is not possible via Azure AD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread
So this means the other partners connect via Sharepoint app only

I mean, they are not supported by SharePoint itself (has nothing to do with PNP) for app-only authentication. The sharepoint apps (when you register an app with SharePoint only) were discontinued awhile ago, now you only have azure apps. Note that microsoft graph sharepoint API surprisingly does support client secrets. So it's kind of messy.
